# “hidden parent” for a git commit?

Tags: git, branch

I’d like to attach a branch to a git commit in a way that it does *not* show up the usual tools (e.g. in `git log`), but it is contained in the git repository and will be as long as the commit itself is, and moves to other repositories together with that commit.

Something like a parent of a commit, but ignored by most tools.

My use case is: I work on a feature branch that I regularly rebase to produce nice clean self-contained test-suit-passing patches; eventually I am going to push this cleaned branch to master. But I’d also like to attach something like the branch’s reflog to it, so I can still obtain the history of the branch, if I later remember that some intermediate state has something worth looking at.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Perhaps [`git notes`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) can be useful?

Comment: Possibly, but they are not automatically pulled and cloned, are they? Also, can a git note itself reference a commit object (instead of just text)?

Comment: Git's "notes" are sort of like this but because note refs live in `refs/notes/` they don't normally follow repositories either.  They're by SHA-1 ID though, so *you* can keep track: as long as the commit ID remains the same in other repositories, your own notes can still be found by that ID.

Comment: “In principle, a note is a regular Git blob, and any kind of (non-)format is accepted.” – indeed, that might work good enough